# exporting pdf file names in a folder to excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a code to give me path and there names for all the files in a folder to excel. 
But my problem is its giving me file names of all the files in that folder. I just want to search and retrieve names of only pdf files to excel.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub Example1()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Range("H1").Value)

i = 1

'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
'print file path
Cells(i + 3, 2) = objFile.Path
i = i + 1
Next objFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `dir()` instead.

Comment: You will need to add an `If` statement that looks at the `right` 3 characters in `objfile` name. If it equals 'pdf' then do your stuff, else do nothing.

Comment: Where exactly I  need to make the changes. If you help on that it would be great.

Comment: Scott has the better idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the comments.  You need to test if the last three characters are 'pdf'

So in your `for` loop add the if statement

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    if right(objFile.Path,3) = "pdf" then
       'print file path
        Cells(i + 3, 2) = objFile.Path
        i = i + 1
    end if
Next objFile
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub Find_PDF()

Dim FileToCheck As String, FilePath As String, FileWildCard As String

FilePath = "c:\YOUR FILE PATH\"
FileWildCard = "*.pdf"

FileToCheck = Dir(FilePath & FileWildCard)

Do While FileToCheck <> ""

    i = i + 1

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value = FileToCheck

    FileToCheck = Dir()

Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a free coding service but i would answer this anyway:

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    if right(objFile.Path,3) = "pdf" then
       'print file path
        Cells(i + 3, 2) = objFile.Path
        i = i + 1
    end if
 msgbox ("Answer are here dont troll on someone")
Next objFile
```